# Java Application executed from Desktop

Tags: java

I have made a java application in Eclipse and it has a Main class which has the main method from which the application runs. I want that i should be able to run the application from outside the eclipse maybe by clicking on some icon.

Can anyone guide how that might be possible?

Answer (score 2):

- [Create a Java .exe/.jar file](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/java/soa/Ask-the-Java-expert-Create-a-Java-exe-file/0,339024620,320283101,00.htm)
- [Create JAR file in Java & Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html)

---

**JAR file using Eclipse IDE**

- [Right click on your project, which you want to create a JAR file of. And select Export from the context menu.](http://img.viralpatel.net/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-eclipse-step1.jpg)
- Select JAR file from Java folder and click Next.
- Provide the Destination path and click on Finish to create the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the application first,then you'll find a file with the extension ".jar" in the project's directory

you can run this jar anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a Jar, you might also deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).

JWS can do desk-top integration tasks like providing a desktop icon (with customized icon) and/or menu item.  JWS also offers many other nice features like configurable automatic update & file associations, and offers a comprehensive API that is only available to JWS apps.  The [JNLP API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html) makes persistence, single instance code and other things easy.